# How to read Firebase Database entry in Firebase Cloud Functions' index.js?

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create device to device push notifications for an iOS app using Firebase Cloud functions. I want to trigger an event whenever a new child is created in database at reference '/user-notifications/{notificationRecipientUid}/{challengeId}'. Here is my index.js code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendWinLoseOrTieNotification = functions.database.ref('/user-notifications/{notificationRecipientUid}/{challengeId}').onWrite(event => {
...
const challengeId = event.params.challengeId;

functions.database.ref('/challenges/' + challengeId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    const challengerUid = snapshot.val().challengerUid;
    ...
});
});
```

When a new child is added in the database at that location, I get this error, "TypeError: functions.database.ref(...).once is not a function", in Firebase Console's Functions Logs. So there is no 'once' method available
 on ref like in web api:

`firebase.database().ref('...').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  ...
});`

My question is: How to read an existing database value inside index.js?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, the solution is to use admin instead of firebase like so:

```
admin.database().ref('...').once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
    ...
});
```

Comment: The reason for this is that you import the admin SDK into a const called `admin`: `const admin = require('firebase-admin')`

Comment: I get an error 500 while using this code, and I don't get how to debug.. Webhook call failed. Error: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: @Waza_Be I'm not a web dev, but I think webhook is for loading external packages like firebase-functions, node mailer etc. You have to install it in your computer for requiring such packages, as in: const functions = require('firebase-functions');
In this case, you are not deploying to your machine but a google server, which has all the webhooks installed, so you will not get this error there.

Comment: @Waza_Be Do this, if you haven't already:
npm install firebase-functions@latest --save
npm install -g firebase-tools
Go to project directory and run:
firebase login
firebase init functions
Put code in functions/index.js, then run:
firebase deploy --only functions
I think that will do. Check https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started for detailed guide.